# How to rezise the contents of a QMainWindow according to window size

Tags: qt, qmainwindow

I have a QMainWIndow with several widgets, one of which is a QTableView.

The Main WIndow is resizable.

How do I resize the contents of the window automatically, the font and everything, i.e. when the window is resized, its contents should also get resized automatically?

I'd appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: Did you place your widgets into a layout?

Comment: resizing the fonts need to be done manually. But this is very tricky, as resizing fonts may trigger a new sizing of your widget, and of your main window.

Comment: @Hank - I have a Vertical box inside the window. In that window I've 3 widgets, 1 uses a Grid Layout, and has QLablels, the other a TableView using a TableLayout. If the table is resized, the contents within these should also be resized...Kindly advise.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with standard Qt mechanics as what you describe differs from what is considered the default behaviour (resize any application - the font size usually stays the same). You could probably override [QWidget::render()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#render-2) or similar and use `scale` on the supplied `QPainter`. I'm not sure if this cascades through the subwidgets though, and even if so, border lines etc would be scaled as well.

Comment: @TimMeyer I see. This would be quite a complex thing keeping track of properties of each subwidget. I'll give your suggestion a go.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

you should put all of your widgets into a layout, layout(s) automatically resize all of your widget(s) inside QMainWindow when user made any change in QMainWindow's size, you can add layout both via Qt Creator IDE and Coding.

UPDATE:

if you add layouts in Qt Creator, layouts automatically coded in moc file and no need to made any changes in their behaviour via coding by user.

but via coding in class constructor:

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(parent);

layout->addWidget(widget1);   
layout->addWidget(widget2);   
layout->addWidget(widget3);   

this->setLayout(layout);
```

but if want to change QLabel's font, this is done by **resizeEvent** in QMainWindow, so for any change in size of MainWindow, **resizeEvent**  triggered, so you use this code:

in **mainwindow.h** you declare **resizeEvent**:

```
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event);
```

in **mainwindow.cpp** implement **resizeEvent**:

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    MainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
    if(this)
    {
        // QLabel process
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a vertical box with 3 widgets inside. Should I add a layout to the main WIndow? and if so, what layout should I choose? I don't wish to affect how it looks now.

Comment: I did that. Didn't help. There was no resizing of any font or content.

Comment: it's really simple, I can not understand what do yo want to do? you want to change in your font size? and your widget contents? which means contents? which widget do you use? for change in font size you must do it with     QFont font("Arial");
    font.setBold(true);
    this->setFont(font);
    this->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

Comment: I have a MainWindow with 3 widgets. These widgets are in a QVerticalBox. 1 of those widgets is a mix of QLabels in a QGridLayout, and the other is a QTableView. What I wish to know, is a way that would allow the resizing of the font ( let's say ), automatically, as I resize the Main WIndow. As of now, it doesn't happen. The content of the window stays the same size, when I expand or reduce the Main Window size.